# PHP crashes when executing large mutation query in GraphQL (Laravel + Lighthouse)

Tags: php, laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

I'm upgrading all libraries of a large web application, ugrading from PHP 7.4, MySQL 5.7, Laravel 8, laravel-lighthouse 4 to PHP 8.2, MySql 8, Laravel 10, laravel-lighthouse 6.
All went well, except some large mutations in GraphQL make PHP crash with
`INFO exited: php (exit status 139; not expected)`.
AFAIK status 139 should be segmentation fault.

The infrustructure is based on docker multiple containers, the problem is the same on developement, where there is Laravel Sail, and on staging server, where there is Laradock.
All is at its last version.

The mutation creates multiple instances of the same class: with just a few of them it works, when numbers grow (around 100 objects) it fails.
Here follows one single item of such mutation:

```
mutation {
    z0: createRateDay(
        input: {day: "2022-01-01", is_open: true, sell_limit: 0, sold_rates: 0, base_amount: 0, rate_id: "3d08ac78-7eb0-11ec-b950-0242ac130006", package_id: "3ce3978a-7eb0-11ec-9348-0242ac130006", room_type_id: "d090ea02-0509-11e8-b131-005056043a6b"}
    ) {
        id
        day
        is_open
        sell_limit
        sold_rates
        base_amount
        rate_id
        package_id
        room_type_id
        rateDayAgeAmounts {
            id
            amount
            number_of_guests
            age {
                id
                name
                __typename
            }
            __typename
        }
        __typename
    }

}
```

How can I detect what is wrong? I have no experience in such low level issues.
Any advise what can I do to mitigate the problem? It was good with older libraries' versions, so I guess I'm not making impossible mutation queries.

I set memory_limit in php.ini to 768M once, and later to 1536M, but if fails anyway.
phpInfo shows the setting is valid and active.
I tryed downgrading to PHP 8.1 with no luck.
I tryied changing the libravy version of laravel-lighthouse from v6 to v5, with no luck.

It's worth saying that such large mutation queries worked flawlessly with the old stack (PHP 7.4, MySQL 5.7, Laravel 8, memory_limit=768MB).

Comment: Create swap file on your server. If your server RAM size is under 4GB, create a swap file 4GB.

Comment: Thanks EHF Shahab, my dev server has plenty of RAM, and i tryed setting even memory_limit=4096M, the result is the same. It seems it's not a memory limit problem.

Comment: The current solution is splitting the large mutation into more requests, each containing not more the 50 mutations. Discovering why it worked on the old stack and it fails on the new one, it's beyond my abilities.